# DC Analysis of Common Collector Circuit with current source at emitter

Tags: transistors, analog, dc, common-collector

For the circuit below I have to derive I<sub>B</sub>, R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub>

[image]
Since it is a DC-analysis, I turn the AC-sources off and make the capacitors open circuits. So the circuit becomes the following

[image]

I<sub>B</sub> is straight forward as we have I<sub>E</sub> and BF = 330.
I<sub>B</sub>= I<sub>C</sub>/BF = 30.3 uA

When it comes to the resistors R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> I don't know how to proceed.
I can calculate U<sub>B</sub> = U<sub>BE</sub> + U<sub>E</sub> = 0.7V + 4.7V = 5.4V (and thus the voltage across R<sub>1</sub> is 4.6V), but because I don't know which currents go into R1 and R2, this is not useful ...

What am I not seeing / considering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When picking resistors for voltage divider bias you can use pretty much any resistances that give you the correct ratio, but in order for it to work well they have to have enough current through them that the base current does not significantly load the divider down. So you need to pick resistors that will have considerably more current through them than \$I_B\$, say an order or two in magnitude higher.

For example, with a base current of 30 uA you would want the divider current to be at least 10 times that, or 300 uA, so simply divide the supply voltage by that and you get a total resistance of around 33.33k. From there you just have to find the ratio of bottom to top resistances. With a voltage of 10 V it's easy, you want 5.4 V so the bottom resistor has to be 0.54 times the total, or around 18k, and the top resistor would be 33k minus that, or around 15k.

Comment: Note that, from the data sheet, BF could be as low as about 200, making Ib = 50uA. So maybe R1+R2 = 20K and R2 = 11K R1 = 9.1K.